# Images not showing up after using mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I have a VirtualHost set up so that it redirects webpages to a cleaner url however images and the .css do not appear.

The paths to the .css and images are relative, how can I fix them without editing the other files? I have the images stored under the root in a images folder but otherwise the .php and stylesheet are in the root

Comment: Sounds like a Server Fault question...

Comment: I guess you'll have to rewrite the urls of the css and the images as well